# Matrix with entries i*j

Tags: matrices

What is a matrix $A_{ij} = i\cdot j$ called?

Let $v = (0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots, \infty)$ and $Tr_n(v) = (0, 1, \ldots, n)$.

Then

$$Tr_n(v)^T Tr_m(v) = 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 0       &  0       & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 1\cdot1 &  1\cdot2 & \dots & 1\cdot(m-1) & 1\cdot(m) \\
    0       & 2\cdot1 &  2\cdot2 & \dots & 2\cdot(m-1) & 2\cdot(m) \\
    \vdots & \vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots \\
    0       & (n-1)\cdot1 &  (n-1)\cdot2 & \dots & (n-1)\cdot(m-1) & (n-1)\cdot(m) \\
    0       & n\cdot1 &  n\cdot2 & \dots & n\cdot(m-1) & n\cdot(m) \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

For $m = n$ this matrix is a diagonalizable symmetric matrix which surely has a name?

Comment: Whatever it is called, it is not positive definite.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Oops, was thinking of something else... anyways, irrelevant, I just need the name.

Comment: I didn't find anything about this matrix on this wikipedia page. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_matrices

Comment: @Suzet I didn't either when I looked there, I expected to do so... It is a very common matrix, in fact and it has nice properties(can be factorized greatly).

Comment: Its name is the multiplication table. https://www.canstockphoto.com.au/multiplication-table-template-31718462.html

Comment: Just to second @GerryMyerson, I would like to say that his is the obvious and only possible answer.